# A query on a (probability?) question and if it is unsolvable due to lack of information

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains n black balls.

A step consists of adding 2n red balls to the urn, mixing thoroughly, and drawing 2n balls from the urn, uniformly at random.

What is the expected number of steps until no black balls remain in the urn?

Comment: It depends on how you put rice into the container and how you take it out, and perhaps also on the mass of a single grain

Comment: This question reminds me of a well-known question about the probability that you just breathed an atom once breathed by [some famous person]. If this is a correct analogy, then the answer depends critically on the size (or mass) of one grain of rice. For example, see https://futurism.com/estimating-how-many-molecules-you-breathe-that-were-from-julius-caesars-last-breath

Comment: Although I agree with the previous comments, I suspect you actually have a question somewhat like this in mind: An urn contains $n$ black balls.  A step consists of adding $2n$ red balls to the urn, mixing thoroughly, and drawing $2n$ balls from the urn, uniformly at random.  What is the expected number of steps until no black balls remain in the urn?  If this is so, amend your question, and I will answer it.

Comment: Saulspatz, I think you are right, that should be the question. Thanks for Henry and awkward as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some kind of variant on the coupon collector's problem, so we expect the answer to be logarithmic in $n$.  I haven't figured out how to do a complete analysis, but it's easy to compute for small values of $n$.

Fix $n$, and let $E(b)$ be the expected number of steps when $b$ black balls remain.  We have $E(0)=0$ obviously, and $E(1)=\frac32$ because the probability of drawing the black ball is $\frac23$, and the number of steps is geometrically distributed.

When $n\ge b>1$, we have $$E(b)=1+\sum_{k=0}^bp(b,k)E(b-k),\tag1$$ where $p(b,k)$ is the probability of drawing exactly $k$ black balls out of $b$ remaining.  That is,
$$p(b,k)=\frac{\binom bk\binom{3n-b}{2n-k}}{\binom{3n}{2n}}$$

In $(1)$, $E(b)$ appears on both sides of the equation, because we might draw $0$ black balls.  It is, of course easy to remedy this by solving for $E(b)$.  Perhaps I should explain that in $(1)$, the sum on the right-hand side is the expected number of draws subsequent to the current, so we have to add $1$ to account for the current draw.

I wrote a little python script to test this for $n$ a multiple of $10$ between $10$ and $300$.

```
from math import factorial, log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''
n black ball are place in an urn
The following step is repeated until no black ball remains
Add 2n red balls to the jar, then remove 2n balls, uniformly
at random.
What is the expected number of steps?
'''

def choose(n,m):
    if m>n: 
        return 0
    return factorial(n)//(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))

def wait(n):
    E = (n+1)*[0]
    E[1] = 1.5
    denominator = choose(3*n, 2*n)
    def p(b,k):
        return choose(b,k)*choose(3*n-b,2*n-k)/denominator
    for b in range(2,n+1):
        E[b] = (1+sum(p(b,k)*E[b-k] for k in range(1,b)))/(1-p(b,0))
    return E[n]
       
xs = list(range(10,301,10))
ys = [wait(x) for x in xs]
zs = [log(x)+.5 for x in xs]
plt.plot(xs,ys,'r')
plt.plot(xs,zs, 'b')
plt.show()

for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
    print(x,y)
```

This gave me the following graph:[image]

The red curve is $E(n)$ and the blue curve is $\log(n)+\frac12$.

I tend to doubt that the constant $\frac12$ remains appropriate as $n$ gets large, but I strongly suspect that the logarithm does.  I think $\log(n)$ is a good approximation to the answer.

I'd like to do a more complete analysis of the problem, but I don't have time at the moment.  If I can get time in the next couple of days, (and no one has posted such an analysis yet), I'll see what I can do.  I would think one just needs to modify the analysis of the usual coupon collector's problem.

**EDIT**

I've done some more work on this.  First, I extended the numerics out to $n=500$, and saw the same behavior as before.

Here's a table of $E(n)-\ln n$ for some values of $n$:

```
300 0.519971592933751
310 0.51680497324943
320 0.5137400797666478
330 0.5107720009081689
340 0.5078961862584093
350 0.5051083728160881
360 0.5024045316520604
370 0.4997808299956832
380 0.4972336048200301
390 0.494759344855769
400 0.49235467866067406
410 0.4900163669311839
420 0.48774129768632424
430 0.4855264833041648
440 0.48336905866359725
450 0.4812662798552658
460 0.479215523086844
470 0.47721428353040896
480 0.47526017395130626
490 0.4733509230256523
500 0.4714843733025216
```

The problem can be formulated in terms of the coupon collector's problem with groups of coupons.  Imagine that the balls are numbered from $1$ to $3n$, and that we want to collect one of each.  We draw them in groups of $2n$.  The balls are initially colored black, and we color all the black balls we draw red, before replacing all the balls in the urn.  So the problem is, what is the expected time to complete the set of all $3n$ numbers, after we have drawn $2n$ of them.

The problem of coupon-collecting with groups is consider in [this article](http://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf) especially section $4$. Note that in our case, the assumption that there are no duplicate coupons in a group is fulfilled.

The article does not consider the problem of the expected time to complete a set after a certain number of coupons have been collected, but I think the methods of the paper could be extended to handle this case.  I haven't tried to do so, because it seems like it would be difficult to establish an approximation formula for it.  The formula given in the paper is rather formidable:
[image]
I apologize for posting an image, but the probability of my typing this correctly is negligible.  The authors of the article don't even attempt to give an approximation formula.

This problem is of some practical interest. Suppose you collect baseball cards, and they come in packets of $5$ at some price $p$ per packet.  You can also buy cards of specific players at a higher price of $c$ per card.  At what point is it cheaper to buy all the remaining individual cards needed to complete your set, rather than continuing to buy packets?  This was the basis of an interesting [programming puzzle](https://gscap.com.br/solucao-do-giant-puzzle-4-colecionador/) that I had a lot of fun doing.

I think the next step is to try the problem when there are different fractions of the coupon set remaining.